# git hook to batch unstage all files in a path

Tags: git, hook, pre-commit-hook, unstage

I have a `devlog` folder where I write down my thoughts/example codes which I like to be visible with `git status`. With the exclusion of these files, quite often I can just `git add .; git commit`, but obviously the contents in `devlog` prohibit that. I like to have a git hook which would unstage the whole path and its contents before commit.

I tried:

```sh
git rm --cached devlog/*
```

But apparently, it expects all contents of `./devlog` to be staged already (including those ignored by `.gitignore`) and hence throws an error:

```
git rm --cached devlog/*
#> fatal: pathspec 'devlog/check.log' did not match any files
```

Where `devlog/check.log` is ignored and has not been staged at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that seems to work. Simply add to `.git/hooks/pre-commit` the following:

```
git reset -- devlog/*
```

Comment: I believe you mean `.git/hooks/pre-commit` (unless you've customized the default path)

Comment: @Anthony Yes I just fixed it. Thanks for the note.

Answer (score 0):

You could:

- force adding `check.log` first,
- then `git rm --cached` everything

Since `check.log` is ignored (listed in `.gitignore`), it would be ignored (again) automatically after the `git rm --cached`.

So:

```sh
    git add --force devlog/check.log
    git rm --cached devlog/*
```

Comment: Thanks. The main issue with this solution is that I will have to update the hook every time I update .gitignore

Comment: @AlJAbadi Why updating the hook multiple times? Only once should be enough.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your proposition correctly. I assume if, for instance, I have `**/*.pdf` in my .gitignore and someday, I start having a pdf file in `./devlog` (or I update my .gitignore to ignore certain file types), I'll have to also `add --force` it in the hook. Please clarify if I'm wrong.